# List in ColumnText is loosing data that is present when added to the document directly

Tags: java, itext

I'm using iText 5.1.3.  The list in the ColumnText isn't complete as shown by the complete list successfully implemented when it is added to the document.  If I uncomment the line:

```
// list2.add(new ListItem(new Chunk("Level 2 - Item 3")));
```

they both appear to be the same; However, the list format I want is with the line removed compeletely.

```
public class TestList
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException
    {
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("testlist.pdf"));
        document.open();
        List list1 = new List(List.ALPHABETICAL, 20);
        list1.add(new ListItem(new Chunk("Level 1 - Item 1")));
        list1.add(new ListItem(new Chunk("Level 1 - Item 2")));
        list1.add(new ListItem(new Chunk("Level 1 - Item 3")));

        List list2 = new List(List.ORDERED, 20);
        list2.add(new ListItem(new Chunk("Level 2 - Item 1")));
        list2.add(new ListItem(new Chunk("Level 2 - Item 2")));

        List list3 = new List(List.ORDERED, 20);
        list3.add(new ListItem(new Chunk("Level 3 - Item 1")));
        list3.add(new ListItem(new Chunk("Level 3 - Item 2")));
        list3.add(new ListItem(new Chunk("Level 3 - Item 3")));
        list3.add(new ListItem(new Chunk("Level 3 - Item 4")));
        list2.add(list3);

        // list2.add(new ListItem(new Chunk("Level 2 - Item 3")));
        list1.add(list2);

        list1.add(new ListItem(new Chunk("Level 1 - Item 4")));
        document.add(list1);
        document.newPage();

        ColumnText cols = new ColumnText(writer.getDirectContent());
        cols.setSimpleColumn(36, 36, 549, 806);
        cols.addElement(list1);
        cols.go();

        document.close();
    }
}
```

How can I get this desired behavior in the ColumnText as well.  I've tried everything I can think of and am at a loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea why it works, but I was just playing around and if you change the commented out line to list2.add(""); it works as expected.  Seems more like a hack to me though.  The final code looks like:

```
public class TestList
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException
    {
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("testlist.pdf"));
        document.open();
        List list1 = new List(List.ALPHABETICAL, 20);
        list1.add(new ListItem(new Chunk("Level 1 - Item 1")));
        list1.add(new ListItem(new Chunk("Level 1 - Item 2")));
        list1.add(new ListItem(new Chunk("Level 1 - Item 3")));

        List list2 = new List(List.ORDERED, 20);
        list2.add(new ListItem(new Chunk("Level 2 - Item 1")));
        list2.add(new ListItem(new Chunk("Level 2 - Item 2")));

        List list3 = new List(List.ORDERED, 20);
        list3.add(new ListItem(new Chunk("Level 3 - Item 1")));
        list3.add(new ListItem(new Chunk("Level 3 - Item 2")));
        list3.add(new ListItem(new Chunk("Level 3 - Item 3")));
        list3.add(new ListItem(new Chunk("Level 3 - Item 4")));
        list2.add(list3);

        list2.add(""); // Changed line.
        list1.add(list2);

        list1.add(new ListItem(new Chunk("Level 1 - Item 4")));
        document.add(list1);
        document.newPage();

        ColumnText cols = new ColumnText(writer.getDirectContent());
        cols.setSimpleColumn(36, 36, 549, 806);
        cols.addElement(list1);
        cols.go();

        document.close();
    }
}
```

Must have something to do with closing the list at level 2.  I've seen this question all over the place and never answered, so I hope someone finds this helpful.